# ambari REST API + how to get all versions from ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp

from ambari we can capture all version , by click on `Admin` button and the click on `stack and version`

finally click on `Versions` , then we get the following details

[image]

we want to know how to capture all these version by using ambari rest api?

we try

```
 curl -u admin:admin -H 'X-Requested-By:admin' 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP/configuratons/service_config_versions'
```

but its not return any info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format should work:

```
http://{HOSTNAME}:{PORT}/api/v1/stacks/HDP/versions/{STACKVERSION}/services?fields=StackServices/service_version
```

So for your example:

```
curl -k -u admin:admin -H 'X-Requested-By:admin' -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stacks/HDP/versions/2.6/services?fields=StackServices/service_version'
```